# Play 2 form limitation

Tags: forms, validation, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to authenticate users through remote authentication service. I've written helper method for sending message to service and waiting for result:

```
def authenticateAwait(email:       String,
                      password:    String
                     ): Either[String, Option[User]] = {
  try {
    val future = authenticate(email, password)
    Right(Await.result(future, timeout.duration))
  } catch {
    case _ ⇒ Left("Unable to connect to authentication server")
  }
}
```

It returns `Left[String]` with an error description if message can't be sent, or there is no response. If service response received, it returns `Right[Option[User]]`. Service responds with `Option[User]` depending on authentication result.

To perform actual authentication I've created form with a couple of validators, here it is:

```
val loginForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "email"    → email,
    "password" → nonEmptyText
  ) verifying ("Invalid email or password", result => result match {
    case (email, password) ⇒
      User.authenticateAwait(email, password) match {
        case Left(_) ⇒ true
        case Right(optUser) ⇒ optUser.isDefined
      }
  }) verifying ("Unable to connect to authentication server", result => result match {
    case (email, password) ⇒
      User.authenticateAwait(email, password) match {
        case Left(_) ⇒ false
        case Right(optUser) ⇒ true
      }
  })
)
```

One thing worries me about this code, it calls `authenticateAwait` twice. It means exactly two messages will be sent per single validation. What I actually need, is to call `authenticateAwait` once, store result and perform various validations on it. It seems there is no simple solution.

To perform authentication, access to the form fields required, it means the form should be bound and then validated, but there is no way to attach errors to the existing form(am I wrong?).

Errors can be attached to the form only during its creation, therefore I should perform authentication in the validators, but then aforementioned problem occurs.

The temporary solution I came with is to define a method and a `var` inside it.

```
def loginForm = {
  var authResponse: Either[String, Option[commons.User]] = null

  Form(
    tuple(
      "email"    → email,
      "password" → nonEmptyText
    ) verifying ("Invalid email or password", result ⇒ result match {
      case (email, password) ⇒
        authResponse = User.authenticateAwait(email, password)
        authResponse match {
          case Left(_) ⇒ true
          case Right(optUser) ⇒ optUser.isDefined
        }
    }) verifying ("Unable to connect to authentication server", result ⇒ result match {
      case (email, password) ⇒
        authResponse match {
          case Left(_) ⇒ false
          case Right(optUser) ⇒ true
        }
    })
  )
}
```

This is clearly a hack. Are there any better solutions?

**Update:**
In my opinion, form should only sanitize input, but authentication should be performed later outside the form.
The problem is that errors are sent to the view as a part of the `Form` and it is impossible to attach errors to the existing form. There are no simple way of creating new form with the errors too.

Comment: it's called AJAX; use it and you won't create ginormous code blocks trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist (hint: there is no need to create a new form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to understand is that Form is immutable. But there is a easy to use utility method to construct a new form with errors added:

```
loginForm.copy(errors = Seq(FormError("email", "Already registered")))
```

Answer (score 0):

sure, conflating authentication with validation just makes a simple operation complex. Below is untested, but this is the direction I would go in, right projections filtered through a for comprehension.

```
// point of validation is to sanitize inputs last I checked
val form = Form(tuple("email"→ email, "password"→ nonEmptyText)
val res = for{
  case(e,p) <- form.bindFromRequest.toRight("Invalid email or password")
  success   <- User.authenticateAwait(e,p).right 
} yield success
res fold( Conflict(Left(_)), u=> Ok(Right(u)) )
```

Comment: Play samples contain authentication inside the form verify block, therefore verifiers is a way to go. Following your solution, if authentication fails, how should I return form with an error back to the template?

Comment: it's already doing that, the Left contains either form validation error, or connection error; Right contains the user apparently...anyway, just wrap it up in a Result, Conflict(Left(_)), u=>Ok(Right(u))

Comment: also, I would assume given that you are taking the futures route, that performance is critical; as such, in a standard web app. ajax would be the way to go, IMO -- that way there is no need to re-display the form on error, user never goes anywhere, you just deal with the error condition and display it, or return success and handle accordingly.